# Delete/Disable windows scheduled task Remotely

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Created one Windows Scheduled Task in Remote Server, task action is **logoff** the user and this task will trigger when specific user had logged in. Here by mistakenly I had selected **any user** instead of **specific user**. Now how can I delete/disable that scheduled task on Remote windows server using my windows machine.

Comment: `SCHTASKS /Delete  /S system /U username /P password  /TN taskname /F`   ?

Comment: @npocmaka sorry, I had not remembered taskname, is there anyway to retrieve all tasks from that system?

Comment: `SCHTASKS /Query  /S system /U username /P password /TN /FO LIST /V`

Comment: You can read the help file by typing: `schtasks /?` at the the cmd prompt. This way you don't have to ask so many questions.

Comment: @npocmaka comment worked as champ, my issue has resolved. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can employ `Get-ScheduledTask`, `Disable-ScheduledTask` and `Unregister-ScheduledTask` to retrieve, disable and delete scheduled tasks. These work on the local PC by default, but you can employ Powershell remoting to run these cmdlets on a remote computer. You can also use `-CimSession` parameter to retrieve data from remote computer.

`Schtasks.exe` also has `/query` parameter and can return all the tasks from a remote computer, so you can then use `schtasks /delete` as said in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$servers = get-content ".\serverslist.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  Unregister-ScheduledTask -CimSession $server -TaskName "TaskName" -Confirm:$false
}
```